# Plotting several lines in matplotlib when points of each line are given gradually

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot several lines in a figure. All points of each line aren't available at the beginning, they become available gradually.

[I want to plot something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvjS9.png)

Whole points for each line aren't available at the beginning, for example at t=3 points for a line is [(1,0),(2,3), (3,6)] and in t=4 a new point comes [(1,0),(2,3), (3,6), (4, 9)].

To be more clear, I don't have all points for drawing, point are given gradually. Therefore, I need to constantly update my plot in order to catch changes.

Answer (score 1):

A picture like this can be plotted with:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint  

data = [ 
    ("1 line", [randint(0, 10) / 10 for i in range(20)]),
    ("2 line", [randint(0, 10) / 10 for i in range(20)]),
    ("3 line", [randint(0, 10) / 10 for i in range(20)]),
    ("4 line", [randint(0, 10) / 10 for i in range(20)])
]

for label, y in data:
    plt.plot(y, label = label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it's not my question, whole points for each line aren't available at the beginning, for example at t=3 points for a line is [(1,0),(2,3), (3,6)] and in t=4 a new point comes [(1,0),(2,3), (3,6), (4, 9)].
I can plot one line in this situation. But I have no Idea for several lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update matplotlib artist data each time you receive new values. At first you plot line with no data like:

```
l = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')[0]
```

and later update data with

```
l.set_data(ydata, xdata)
```

Don't forget redraw with

```
plt.draw()
```

If you have more lines, plot function returns list of artists, so each need to be updated.